# upload multiple images with system the validation not work

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I tried to upload multiple images using validation system, even I upload the jpeg type images it gives me validation system error The images must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png, gif, svg.

**register.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     @csrf
<div class="form-group" id="divim">
            <label>photos<span class="text-hightlight">*</span></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="images[]" value="{{ old('images') }}" multiple>
            @error('images')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
        
         <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('Register') }}
            </button>
         </div>
       </form>
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
     'images' => ['bail','required','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','max:2048']
        ]);
    }
```

**method create/store**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    { 
$dataim = array();
         if($request->hasFile('images'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('images') as $file) 
            {
                $namee = encrypt($file->getClientOriginalName()).'.'.$file->extension();
                //$name = encrypt($namee).'.'.$file->extension();
                $name = "profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\\".$namee;
                $file->storeAs("public\\profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year, $namee); 
                //$Annonce->images = "annonces\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\\".time().'.'.$image->extension();  
                array_push($dataim,$name);
            }
         }
        $user->images=json_encode($dataim);
        $imm =$user->images;
return User::create([
 'images'       => $imm
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to validate an array, you have to structure your rules differently:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'images' => ['bail', 'required', 'array', 'min:1'],
    'images.*' => ['bail', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg', 'max:2048'],
]);
```

See the [docs on validating arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-arrays) for more information.